# How can i pass 8 arguments to assembly x64 procedure from C#

Tags: c#, assembly, x86-64, masm, calling-convention

I have to pass 8 arguments to procedure.

I have tried passing directly 8 arguments but im getting object reference not set to instance an object. I tried passing one big structure as a pointer with 8 params in it but i cannot read 6th,7th and 8th argument, and tied passing 2 structures as pointers but cannot read 3 from 4 arguments from 2nd structure

c#

```
public unsafe struct Pointers
    {
        public int* intputArray;
        public int width;
        public int* outputArray;
        public int height;
        public int* gx;
        public int startY;
        public int* gy;
        public int endY;

    }

unsafe
        {
            fixed (Pointers* strc=&structToASM) {
                fixed (int* ptr3 = &gx[0], ptr4 = &gy[0], ptr = &input[0], ptr2 = &output[0]) {
                    
                        structToASM.intputArray = ptr;
                        structToASM.outputArray = ptr2;
                        structToASM.gx = ptr3;
                        structToASM.gy = ptr4;
                        structToASM.width = 1;
                        structToASM.height = 2; //dummy values
                        structToASM.startY = 3;
                        structToASM.endY = 1;

                        ProcessRows(strc);
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

```
    .code 

ProcessRows proc
mov r8,[rcx];input
mov r15d,[rcx+8];width
mov r9,[rcx+16];output
mov r13d,[rcx+24];height
mov r10, [rcx+32];gx
mov r12d,[rcx+48];start ; here i got from presentation from university that next arg is +48 not 40
mov r11,[rcx+56];gy
mov esi, [rcx+64];end

xor r14,r14
loop_:
movups xmm0, [r8 + r14 * 4] 

movups xmm1,[r10+20]
addps xmm0,xmm1

movups [r9 + r14*4],xmm0
inc r14 

cmp r14, r12 ; here im checking if value is loaded it should exit loop, i can get values from width, height not from start, and end
jne loop_

ret
ProcessRows endp
End
```

Comment: The assembly code violates the calling convention by not saving/restoring some callee-save registers (which could crash the C# code after the assembly code returns)

Comment: which registers should i save? In case when i will pass structure with 5 args as a pointer then read then from RCX, and rest argumets (3) I will pass normally and read from RDX, R8, R9

Comment: The MS 64-bit calling convention details are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170#parameter-passing . _The x64 ABI considers registers RBX, RBP, RDI, RSI, RSP, R12, R13, R14, R15, and XMM6-XMM15 nonvolatile. They must be saved and restored by a function that uses them._

Comment: According to [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=msvc-170#register-volatility-and-preservation), the ones that you used but didn't save/restore are RSI and R12 to R15. BTW you're adding some floats here, but originally the data was pointer-to-int, is that ok? Also you're adding 4 of them at once, but then advance the index by only 1.

Comment: You should have been able to pass them all as 8 separate values as well. All of yours were integer class (ints and pointers are integer class and no floats/doubles etc). With all of them being integer class values RCX is param1, RDX is param2, R8 is param 3, R9 is param 4. The 5th parameter is on the stack and that value is at [RSP+40]. 6th parameter at [RSP+48], 7th parameter at [RSP+56], and 8th parameter at [RSP+64]

Comment: Hmm, you have eight 64-bit values here so there shouldn't be any problem with sequentially accessing them (they're naturally aligned so there shouldn't be any padding issues going on). I would have thought you'd be able to read them all no matter if you passed by value or reference.